# Trying to have Eclipse recognize jdk1.8, but I cannot find the folder

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, linux-mint

I'm using linux mint 19.3 and eclipse 2020-06, and I'm trying to get eclipse to recognize java 8 jre. The jre directory that I want to use is located at

`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/`

as shown in this pic.

[image]

So in eclipse, I go to

`Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`

then I click

`Add > Standard VM > Next`

Now I am where the picture shows and I click `Directory`

[image]

Ok so here is the part that is confusing me. I navigate to `/usr/lib` using the eclipse directory tool, but there is no `jvm` directory.

[image]

Also, this `/usr/lib` directory seems very different; it's missing a bunch of things.

This is how the directory looks when I access it using the regular file manager

[image]

It almost seems like I'm accessing some other drive, but that can't be... because I have only one drive.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to fill the _JRE home_ field with `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251` to see whether Eclipse IDE is able to discover it?

Comment: Yep I tried that. I get the message "The home directory does not exist."

Comment: Maybe check the rights on the folder? e.g. do a `chmod 777 -R /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251` then try again to select the directory from Eclipse IDE

Comment: Shux. I liked you idea and I was hoping that it would work. Sadly it doesn't.

Comment: Might be a bug then. I would advise you to ask the question to an [Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/) then consider reporting the issue to [Eclipse's Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.